# How to document optional closure function parameters?

Tags: swift, xcode, closures, documentation, swift4

How do you document the parameters of a function's optional closure parameter in Swift 4?

Let's say that you have a method that takes an optional closure as a parameter.
For example,

```
/// An example function.
/// Documentation goes here.
/// 
/// - Parameters:
///   - optionalClosure:    An optional closure.
///   - aClosureParameter:  This will not be displayed.
func exampleMethod(optionalClosure: ((_ aClosureParameter: Bool) -> Void)?) {
    // Do something
}
```

The aClosureParameter would not be documented. How to document the optional closure parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot tell if that is intentional or a bug, but a workaround is
to declare the parameter type using `Optional` instead of `?`:

```
/// An example function.
/// Documentation goes here.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - optionalClosure:    An optional closure.
///   - aClosureParameter:  This **will** be displayed.
func exampleMethod(optionalClosure: Optional<(_ aClosureParameter: Bool) -> Void>) {
    // Do something
}
```

[image]